# Letting a single Java annotation implicitly set multiple annotations

Tags: java, inheritance, intellij-idea, annotations

I have written a Java library that defines and uses a custom annotation to find methods that are then called via reflection.

See [this](https://github.com/nielsbasjes/yauaa/blob/4fc4511c4e923a25dc16d78c6484a7c15589286b/analyzer/src/test/java/nl/basjes/parse/useragent/annotate/TestAnnotationSystem.java#L61) example

```
@YauaaField("DeviceClass")
public void setDeviceClass(TestRecord record, String value) {
    record.deviceClass = value;
}
```

So IDEs like IntelliJ and probably other code analysis tools will report most of the functions annotated this way as "Unused".

What I would like is an automated way to say that anything that has been annotated with `@YauaaField` is automatically also annotated with `@SuppressWarnings("unused")`.

I've done quite a bit of googling, read through several online manuals, tutorials and java documentation. Yet I have not yet been able to find how to do that. The annotations do not seem to support 'inheritance' of any kind.

So is what I want even possible?

If not then what other options do I have?

So far I have only found these two ways to suppress these needless warnings:

- In IntelliJ I found the manual option to Suppress this warning on all methods annotated with YauaaField. But that is a manual option.
- Manually set the `@SupressWarnings("unused")` on all of those methods/classes.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Well ... why "unused"? What is ununsed in here?

Comment: The setter as shown in my example is not called from anywhere except via the annotation/reflection route. So any code analysis tool will not be able to detect this usage route and will incorrectly report it as unused.

Comment: Still. Imho, neither javac nor eclipse will complain about *unused* for **public** methods. A public method in a public class might be a library interface, no static analysis tool should report such methods as unused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not entirely automated, but a nice workaround. In IntelliJ you can set up your own Live Template to suggest an autocomplete when typing the annotation:

[image]